# How can I add subtitle for each image below figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using subplot to display multiple image in the a figure. I want to add the subtitle (a),(b),...(c) below each image as the below figure:

[image]

Could you help to write it in MATLAB? This is current code for above image. if it is possible, let me know how to control the margin between image and the sub-title. Thanks

```
%# read images in a cell array
imgs = cell(6,1);
for i=1:6
    imgs{i} = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );
end

%# show them in subplots
figure(1)
for i=1:6
    subplot(2,3,i);
    h = imshow(imgs{i}, 'InitialMag',100, 'Border','tight');
    title(num2str(i))
    set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn',{@callback,i})
end
```

Updated: I also tried with subaxis lib. However, the result do not show titles

```
%% read images in a cell array
imgs = cell(6,1);
for i=1:6
    imgs{i} = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );
end

figure(1)
spaceH=0.01;spaceV=0.1;marTop=0.3;marBot=0.0; 
 padding=0.0;margin=0.0;marginL=0.0;
for i=1:6
    subaxis(2,3,i,'SpacingHoriz', spaceH, ...
            'SpacingVert',spaceV, 'PL',padding,'PR',padding,'mt',... 
            marTop,'mb',marBot,'ML',marginL,'MR',margin); title('Original'); 
    imagesc(uint8(imgs{i}),[0 255]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,
    xlabel(['(' char(96+1) ')']);
end
```

Comment: Do you intend to zoom into the images once plotted? And are you planning on having both a title and a subtitle?

Comment: Yes, I want to show it in one figure. No. I just want to insert (a),(b)... bellows the image. The title does not need to show

Comment: As you want to zoom into your subplots, are you zooming vertical, horizontal or into both dimensions?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger: both dimensions. However, the main target is how to insert (a),(b),...below the figure

Comment: My issue was that altering the title position would make the title move upon zoom. However I've found a way to stop that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read solution of mikkola. I would like thank for your help. I would like to post my solution which may be helpful for other people
This is my solution

```
%% read images in a cell array
imgs = cell(6,1);
for i=1:6
    imgs{i} = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );
end

figure(1)
spaceH=0.01;spaceV=0.06;marTop=0.3;marBot=0.08; 
 padding=0.0;margin=0.0;marginL=0.0;
 yoffset = 12;
for i=1:6
    subaxis(2,3,i,'SpacingHoriz', spaceH, ...
            'SpacingVert',spaceV, 'PL',padding,'PR',padding,'mt',... 
            marTop,'mb',marBot,'ML',marginL,'MR',margin); title('Original'); 
%     imagesc(uint8(imgs{i}),[0 255]),colormap(gray);axis equal,
   imshow(imgs{i}, 'InitialMag',90, 'Border','tight');
   xlb{i} = xlabel(['(' char(96+i) ')'],'FontSize', 16);
   xp = get(xlb{i}, 'position');
   xp(2) = xp(2) - yoffset; % update y-position
   set(xlb{i}, 'position', xp); % assign new position
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. To specify a margin just set the 'margin' variable to whatever you need.

```
% show images with subtitles
figure(1);
margin = 0; % margin between title and image (in ex)
title_names = {'(a)','(b)','(c)','(d)','(e)','(f)'};
for i=1:6
    subplot(2,3,i);
    handle_image = imshow(imgs{i}, 'InitialMag',100, 'Border','tight');
    handle_title = title(title_names{i});
    set(handle_image, 'ButtonDownFcn',{@callback,i})

    % adjust title position -- in 2 steps

    % first set the title position to the bottom of the image
    image_height = get(handle_image,'YData');
    image_height(1) = [];
    position = get(handle_title,'Position');
    position(2) = image_height;
    set(handle_title,'Position',position);

    % then move it out of the image and apply some margin
    set(handle_title,'Units','characters');
    position = get(handle_title,'Position');
    position(2) = position(2) - margin - 1;
    set(handle_title,'Position',position);

    % EDIT: this line will keep titles on their relative position
    set(handle_title,'Units','normalized');
end
```

Note that you have to define `@callback` within the same namespace or it will throw an error, whenever you klick on an image.

This is an example result using 'trees.tiff' and a margin of 0.5ex.
[image: example image, showing 6 subplots and their according subtitles]

EDIT: If you want to alter the figure size dynamicly the titles woun't adjust in x direction. To get a similar behavior then classic 'titles' add

```
set(handle_title,'Units','normalized');
```

below all other lines. This will keep the title at the same relative coordinates in the figure instead of the same fixed coordinates.

Comment: Thank FirefoxMetzger. I tested it but your titles look fixed. That means when I zoom in figure, these titles (a),..(f) are fixed, instead of moving with image

Comment: Yes, this is the default behaviour of a subplot. Each axis can be zoomed independantly. Are you trying to zoom the entire figure?

Comment: Yes. I zoom in whole figure

Comment: So I've tried to replicate your situation, but I can't seem to be able to zoom within a figure. I can zoom in an axis, but it doesn't work with a figure. My only quess is that you resize the figure window? If not I would have to ask you to explain in more detail what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for a result such as my picture in question. It also allows to auto change position of label as xlabel function

Comment: I've added a line of code in response to your first comment, assuming you meant that the titles missbehave when resizing the figure. This will work if the figure isn't to small. If this is not what you are looking for, please rephrase your question and tell me why my solution is off. Note that I am altering the position of title() not of xlabel().

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for controlling subplot margins and other properties, I highly recommend the [`tight_subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot) function that may be found at the Mathworks File Exchange.

As for the specific question for adding labels, you can use `xlabel`. Example:

```
figure(1)
for i=1:6
    subplot(2,3,i);
    h = plot(1:20, randn(20,1));
    xlb{i} = xlabel(['(' char(96+i) ')']);
end
```

You can control the location of the label by tuning the `Position` property of the labels, which are actually [`text`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) objects. Example:

```
% Move all xlabels down by yoffset
yoffset = 0.3;
for ii = 1:6
    xp = get(xlb{ii}, 'position');
    xp(2) = xp(2) - yoffset; % update y-position
    set(xlb{ii}, 'position', xp); % assign new position
end
```

Comment: It worked. However, the position between the images so big. Hence, I tried to use subaxis. But it does not show the title. Could you try the lib? Let see my update

Comment: @MoonLee Glad I could help. Sorry, I don't have that library nor time to try it now. If you want, you can control the gaps between the axes e.g. by using the `tight_subplot` function I mentioned. Good luck!

Comment: You can download at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot